# Матрица и кубическое уравнение

Tags: математика, матрицы, линейная-алгебра

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это решить? Или хотя бы что нужно знать чтобы это решить?)) Ответ: -27, посчитал с помощью онлайн калькулятора)

Comment: Если Вам знаком термин в метке "линейная алгебра", то  откуда такие вопросы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да все просто. Достаточно расписать (x-a1)(x-a2)(x-a3) и приравнять к уравнению, и расписать определитель, как все получится - главное, **не решая само уравнение**.

Вот расписано детально. Преобразования на уровне примерно 7-8 класса, самое сложное - возведение (a+b) в куб :) и немного включить голову:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что надо знать? Формулу определителя третьего порядка, теорему Виета... Вроде все.

Comment: В верхней формуле правый члены выглядит как произведение кубов, но между кубами должны быть минусы

Comment: Спасибо большое!) Действительно, все просто)) Не догадался представить кубическое уравнение как произведение((

Comment: @MBo Да, вы правы, я переписывал с другого черновика... Но уже не буду исправлять, ладно? :)

Comment: @Harry Да это автору напоминание